Verifying that dual LP of dual LP is the primal LP: Different result based on sign choice?
I'm following the Convex Optimization course from the Stanford university (the book by Stephen Boyd and Lieven Vandenberghe). I am encountering strange results when verifying that the dual LP of the dual LP is the primal LP. First, some definitions, so there is no need to look for the course materials. Consider a convex optimization problem $$\begin{align*}\text{minimize}\quad &f_0(x)\\\text{subject to}\quad &f_i(x)\leq0,\quad i=1,\ldots,m\\ &Ax=b\end{align*}$$ The Lagrange dual function is defined as infimum of the problem Lagrangian over $x$:
$$ g(\lambda,\nu)=\inf_{x\in\mathcal{D}}\underbrace{\left(f_0(x)+\sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_if_i(x)+\nu^T(Ax-b)\right)}_{L(x,\lambda,\nu)},$$
where $\lambda_i$ and $\nu_i$ are Lagrange multipliers corresponding to the inequality and equality constraints, respectively.For $\lambda \geq0$, we have that $g(\lambda,\nu)$ provides a lower bound on the optimal value of the problem, $p^\star$, i.e. $g(\lambda,\nu)\leq p^\star, \lambda\geq0, \forall \nu$. The dual problem is to find the largest lower bound, so we have
$$\begin{align*}
\mathop{\text{maximize}}_\limits{\lambda,\nu}\quad &g(\lambda,\nu)\\
\text{subject to}\quad &\lambda\geq0.
\end{align*}
$$
Often additional constraints are made explicit to ensure that $g(\lambda,\nu)$ is bounded (not $-\infty$).
Now consider the linear program
$$\begin{align*}
\mathop{\text{minimize}}_\limits{x}\quad &c^Tx\\
\text{subject to}\quad &Ax\leq b.
\end{align*}
$$
The Lagrange dual function is
$$g(\lambda)=-b^T\lambda+\inf_x (c+A^T\lambda)^Tx=\begin{cases}
-b^T\lambda,\quad c+A^T\lambda=0\\-\infty,\quad\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
Making the constraint explicit and renaming $y:=\lambda$, we have the dual problem
$$\begin{align*}
\mathop{\text{maximize}}_\limits{y}\quad &-b^Ty\\
\text{subject to}\quad &A^Ty+c=0\\
&y\geq0.
\end{align*}
$$
which corresponds (changing sign of the criterion) to
$$\begin{align*}
\mathop{\text{minimize}}_\limits{y}\quad &b^Ty\\
\text{subject to}\quad &A^Ty+c=0\\
&y\geq0.
\end{align*}
$$
Now to the point. It seems that the dual of the dual is different whether I take the term corresponding to the equality constraint with a minus sign or a plus sign. That should not matter since $A^Ty+c=0$ is the same as $-A^Ty-c=0$.
If I take the $+$ sign:
$$L(y,\lambda,\nu)=c^Ty{\color{red} +}\nu^T(A^Ty+c)-\lambda^T$$
$$g(\lambda,\nu)=c^T\nu +\inf_y(b+A\nu-\lambda)^Ty=\begin{cases}
c^T\nu,\quad A\nu+b=\lambda\geq0 \\
-\infty,\quad\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
That gets us a problem which is not the primal problem (unless I transform to $x:=-\nu$):
$$\begin{align*}
\text{maximize}\quad &c^T\nu\\
\text{subject to}\quad &A\nu\geq -b
\end{align*}$$
When I take the $-$ sign:
$$L(y,\lambda,\nu)=c^Ty{\color{red} -}\nu^T(A^Ty+c)-\lambda^T$$
$$g(\lambda,\nu)=-c^T\nu+\inf_y(b-A\nu-\lambda)^Ty=\begin{cases}
-c^T\nu,\quad b-A\nu=\lambda\geq0\\
-\infty,\quad\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
which yields the problem equivalent to the primal problem (the minus in the objective is compensated for by the maximization)
$$\begin{align*}
\text{maximize}\quad &-c^T\nu\\
\text{subject to}\quad &A\nu\leq b
\end{align*}$$
What is happening? Why am I getting a different problem (different optimal values and optimal points) when constructing a dual from the same problem, but changing a sign which should not matter? Am I overlooking something?
